# How can I set a pass code in Ricoh MP C2004ex?

Tags: passwords, printer, lock

There is a multi-functional printer (Ricoh MP C2004ex) in my office and I want to set a pass code (number lock) to it. Earlier there was another printer (Ricoh Aficio MP C2030) and it was set in such a way that it will ask for pass code whenever someone tries to use it.

I searched about this in Google and can't find a proper solution. I want to:

- Set a number lock in my machine so that it will ask the code every time before we use it (when it is woke from sleep mode).
- Or, set a number lock to copier and scanner functions and to system settings.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up a user code authorization so users accessing the printer
will need to enter a code in order to use it :

[image]

The user code is created as follows :

1. Log in as the machine administrator from the control panel.
2. Press System Settings
3. Press Administrator Tools
4. Press Next
5. Press User Authentication Management
6. Select User Code Auth.
   If you do not want to enable user authentication, select Off.
7. In "Functions to Restrict", select the functions that you want to restrict.
   If the function you want to select is not displayed, press Next.
   The selected functions are subject to User Code authentication. User Code authentication is not applied to the functions not selected.

The default administrator login for most Ricoh printers is User ID : admin,
Password : blank.

Source is [Ricoh manuals](http://support.ricoh.com/bb_v1oi/html/oi/r/model/mpc2004ex/mpc2004exen.htm#) :

- [User Guide](http://support.ricoh.com/bb_v1oi/pub_e/oi/0001069/0001069987/VD2417002A_06/D2417002A.pdf)
- Security Guide : [HTML](http://support.ricoh.com/bb_v1oi/html/oi/r/model/mpc2004ex/mpc2004exen.htm#), [ZIP](http://support.ricoh.com/bb_v1oi/pub_e/oi/0001069/0001069817/VD0AF7092_03/D0AF7092_en.zip)